# Update UI table View from a Static method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, static-methods

I am developing a chat application. Some of my classes are singleton therefore I have use lot of static methods.

When ever a new message is received in app delegate. It should send it to my incomingChat viewController.

I am able to get the new message to static method in viewcontroller. But I cant reload the table from static method.

**InCommingVC.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface InCommingVC : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBarTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *incommingTable;

+ (void) sendIncommingChats:(NSDictionary *) chatDetails;
+ (void) recieveIncomingChat:(NSDictionary *) chatDetails;

@end
```

**InCommingVC.m**

```
#import "InCommingVC.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "IncommingItemObject.h"

static NSMutableArray *incomminglist;

@interface InCommingVC (){
    AppDelegate *delegate;
}

@end

@implementation InCommingVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationBarTitle.topItem.title = @"Incomming Chats";

}



+ (void) recieveIncomingChat:(NSDictionary *) chatDetails{
    NSLog(@"GOT A NEW recieveIncomingChat");
    NSString *CompanyId = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"CompanyId"];
    NSString *ConnectionId = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"ConnectionId"];
    NSString *CountryCode = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"CountryCode"];
    NSString *Department = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"Department"];
    NSString *Name = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *StartTime = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"StartTime"];
    NSString *TimeZone = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"TimeZone"];
    NSString *VisitorID = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"VisitorID"];
    NSString *WidgetId = [chatDetails objectForKey:@"WidgetId"];

    NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    NSLog(@"CompanyId      : %@" , CompanyId);
    NSLog(@"ConnectionId   : %@" , ConnectionId);
    NSLog(@"CountryCode    : %@" , CountryCode);
    NSLog(@"Department     : %@" , Department);
    NSLog(@"Name           : %@" , Name);
    NSLog(@"StartTime      : %@" , StartTime);
    NSLog(@"TimeZone       : %@" , TimeZone);
    NSLog(@"VisitorID      : %@" , VisitorID);
    NSLog(@"WidgetId       : %@" , WidgetId);
    NSLog(@"------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    IncommingItemObject *item = [[IncommingItemObject alloc] init];
    [item setCompanyId:CompanyId];
    [item setConnectionId:ConnectionId];
    [item setCountryCode:CountryCode];
    [item setDepartment:Department];
    [item setName:Name];
    [item setStartTime:StartTime];
    [item setTimeZone:TimeZone];
    [item setVisitorID:VisitorID];
    [item setWidgetId:WidgetId];

    if (incomminglist.count == 0) {
        incomminglist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [incomminglist addObject:item];
        [[InCommingVC incommingTable] reloadData];
    } else {
        [incomminglist addObject:item];
    }

    NSLog(@"count %i", incomminglist.count);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return incomminglist.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"identify_incomming";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.incommingTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    IncommingItemObject *item = [incomminglist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIImageView *CountryImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:5010];
    [CountryImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:item.CountryCode]];

    UILabel *visitorName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5011];
    visitorName.text = item.Name;

    UILabel *visitStartTime = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5012];
    visitStartTime.text = item.StartTime;

    return cell;
}
```

I want to update my `incommingTable` from a static method. can some one help me. tnx.

I am having  this error

> /Users/zupportdesk/Desktop/MyIOSApps/Chat System/Chat
>   System/InCommingVC.m:96:23: No known class method for selector
>   'incommingTable'

while doing

`[[InCommingVC incommingTable] reloadData];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways :

1 - Make a shared instance. Call :

```
[[[self class] sharedInstance].tableView reloadData];
```

2 - Make you class confirm to some notification , that you'll send upon receiving message with payload (chat dictionary). Make sure to deregister the notification when view controller de-allocates

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self.incommingTable reloadData];
```

Try this please and make sure IBOUTLET is proper connected

Comment: hy tnx. ya it is connected properly. it cannot detect self because its a static method.

Comment: Can you use NSNotification instead of static method.I am not sure about your current situation.